# Is there a way to define relationships between create_resources

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

In my puppet class i use 3 create_resources. I want to execute these create_resources in order. Thus there are relationships between each other

```
create_resources(change_config::cr1, $resource)

create_resources(change_config::cr2, $resource)

create_resources(change_config::cr3, $resource)
```

**cr3** should be executed after **cr2** and **cr2** should be after **cr1**.

Is there a way to do this ?

Regards,
Malintha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Puppet Collectors](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html) here. Simply add this line into your manifest:

```
Change_config::Cr1<| |> -> Change_config::Cr2<| |> -> Change_config::Cr3<| |>
```

It will order all Cr1's before 2's before 3s. You can even put extra filtering inside the <|    |> like

```
Change_config::Cr1<| title == 'some_name' |> -> Change_config::Cr1<| <| title != 'some_name' |>
```

Comment: I use this solution. But this do only the first mentioned one. (Cr1). Other create_resource definitions are not working. then I changed the order ( put cr2 to first ). Then it do only Cr2. What is the reason for this ?

Comment: This should work as I described. Can you copy your code here?